# Git Ignore Files per Branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitignore

Goal: only include generated files on specified branches.

Reasons:

1. Generated files cause conflicts
2. Deploy via Git is only option in some environments

So, in current workflow, main branch is dev, there are two deployment branches: stage and prod.

What I would expect to work is adding

```
build/*

[branch "stage, prod"]
    !build/*
```

to .gitignore or .git/info/excludes would mean that after I run `rake build` on dev branch, build/ does not show changed files when run `git status`.  On stage and prod branches, build/ would show changed files.

However, all the variations I've tried of the above have not worked.

This seems like pretty typical workflow, is there some git magic I'm missing or how do people deal with this situation?

Answer (score 9):

`.gitignore` is a file checked into the repository like any other file.  Checkout a branch, change `.gitignore` to how you want it for that branch, and commit it.  That change will only affect that branch.

Comment: This works, but means that every time I rebase dev into stage or prod, will have a conflict in .gitignore to resolve.

Comment: Not a huge deal, but what I'm trying to set up is a dead simple deploy process that goes `git checkout stage`, `rake build`, `git add`, `git commit`, `git push`.  The a web hook posts to the server which in turn fetches the stage branch.  Is there a way to avoid the rebase conflict in .gitignore?

Comment: @ShaeKuronen While it's very temping, Git isn't a release manager and doesn't work well if you try to use it as one. You probably don't want to be deploying all your dev and build artifacts and full dev source to the server anyway. Add a rake task that builds a release, tag it in Git, and ship that tarball/package to the server.

Comment: Yeah, might have to go in that direction, but it would be a lot nicer if didn't need to because (for this type of project ie static sites generated via Middleman) we work with a lot of contractors and there's a fair bit of churn.  So, to have this set up so each contractor can release to staging (and sometimes prod depending on how long we've worked together), would need to get them server creds.  That means I'm managing another set of creds for each developer.  The way Github handles teams is great, so if that set of credentials could also manage deploys, would be optimal.

Comment: @ShaeKuronen There's various ways you can do that. It's better asked as another question.

Answer (score 3):

I found an tuturial what should match your request.
Basicly it is not possible to make differnt ignores per branch.
One way to "fake" this behavoir is:

1. create different exclude-files per branch (exclude.)
2. use hooks to create change as simlink always to the exclude of the current branch

Details how to do this cou can find in [gitignore per branch - Tuturial](https://obda.net/blog/gitignore-per-branch/)